# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error when trying to build Restful Web Service

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jersey

I am trying to build a simple Rest web service by following [this tutorial](http://www.l3oc.com/2015/05/java-rest-web-service.html)

But when i run this project on Eclipse, an Error appears:

```
   Mar 11, 2018 8:39:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [Distance] in web application [/Distance] threw load() exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
    at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
    at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener.process(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.scanClasses(ResourceConfig.java:892)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig._getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:849)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:755)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1181)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.createRuntimeConfig(ResourceConfig.java:1150)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:322)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1066)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5370)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5668)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1690)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Can someone please told me where i am wrong? Thank you in advance. Sorry for my bad English

Comment: You should post some code and show the efforts you have made...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in my Maven project after some open dependencies were updated to new versions. In my case they were

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
    <version>[1.3.2,)</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
    <version>[3.0.1,)</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>[2.5.0,)</version>
</dependency>
```

which respectively downloaded

```
mybatis-spring-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
mybatis-3.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
eclipselink-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I searched for the JARs history inside Maven Respository (usually something like `{user-home}/.m2/repository`) and found all JARs were update the day I got this error.

I restored the JARs' previous version using "closed" dependencies in my `pom.xml`, i.e.:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>**2.5.0**</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
    <version>**1.3.2**</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
    <version>**3.4.6**</version>
</dependency>
```

then update the dependecies. Maven downloaded

```
mybatis-spring-1.3.2.jar
mybatis-3.4.6.jar
eclipselink-2.5.0.jar
```

instead, and all worked fine.

Don't even know whether you're using a pom.xml (Maven Project) but of course you're running Tomcat so check if there are some incompatible or recently modified jar versions inside your

```
{catalina.base}/lib
```

or you web app

```
WEB-INF/lib
```

Hope this helps.